# How does scale(preprocessing) work in python

Tags: python

I want to find mean in python , I used sklearn class preprocessing  in scale it convert the value ,  but I didn't understand the concept , so i want know mathematical formula of the scale , If any one please .

Comment: I don't think I'm alone in finding your question completely 100% incomprehensible. Edit your question after you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the scaler is :

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

Docs : [MinMaxScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)